# communicating with `app module` is not works

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a modal popup. from this I am trying to communicate with my parent ( app module ) finally i think there is no way. But still to clarify I am posting this question.

here is my app template:

```
 <div class="wrapper" [event]="clickedEvent" >
  <header>
    <app-header #dropDownValue></app-header>
  </header>
  <section>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-category-menu [hideDropDownMenu]="dropDownValue.dropDown" ></app-category-menu>
      <footer>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </footer>
  </section>
  <app-cookie-model (eventClicked)="clickedEvent()" ></app-cookie-model>
</div>
```

app component ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    cookieValue = 'UNKNOWN';

    constructor( private cookieService:CookieService ){}

    ngOnInit():void{
        this.cookieService.set( 'retailAppCookies', 'Hello AppCookie' );
        this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('retailAppCookies');
    }

    @Input() clickedEvent(){
        alert('hi'); //not getting any alert
    }

}
```

my modal ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cookie-model',
  templateUrl: './cookie-model.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cookie-model.component.scss']
})
export class CookieModelComponent implements OnInit {

    cookieAlert:boolean = true;

    @Output() eventClicked = new EventEmitter<Event>(); //not triggering!!

    constructor(private cookieService:CookieService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // console.log( this.cookieService.get('retailAppCookies'))
    }

    cookieAgreed(){
        this.eventClicked.emit();
    }

}
```

getting error as :

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'event' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("<div class="wrapper" [ERROR ->][event]="clickedEvent" >
```

Comment: as per error `[event]` what is event here? I guess it should some event name like `mouseover` `click` etc?

Comment: @PardeepJain - I updated to `click` but getting `Can't bind to 'click' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Comment: @3gwebtrain try looking at the angular template cheat sheet. You seem to be making a lot of template mistakes. I suggest browsing through the angular.io website, and look at the basic examples there

Answer (score 0):

The parent can communicate with children, using ViewChild(), but not vice versa, since the child desn't know anything about it's parent...

But you have an output event (eventClicked) - you can listen to it from your parent, and make some actions if needed.

Also you can use a service to make a communication between these components.

And finally, you can use Redux if you want to have a single data storage between all components.

**But here you have a totally different problem.
You have created an input parameter [event] to a div, which doesn't have such input parameter.**

Comment: You are already doing this, using an output event: (eventClicked)="clickedEvent()"

Comment: But I am not getting any trigger in my app module

Comment: `clickedEvent` in your `app.component.ts` doesn't have this `@Input()` decorator, you need this if it's provide from a Parent, remove it, i think it's the problem

Comment: I think the problem is in your call: this.eventClicked.emit();. as I remember, the .emit() requires at least one argument. try using: this.eventClicked.emit(null);